# Down to someone (is it used in AmE?)

Tags: word-usage, american-english

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

[**be down to sb**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/be-down-to-sb)

> It's down to me to find a suitable person for the job.

Is **it's down to me** commonly used in casual conversations?

Like:

> It's **down to me** to find a suitable person for this job.
>
> It's **down to me** to find an ideal vacation location.

Comment: Curiously enough, *It's down to me* can mean *It's up to me*.

Answer (score 2):

"Down to me/you" isn't uncommon in US English. However, the phrase normally only gets used as part of an elimination process. For example, a teacher searching students for notes being passed around might say to the last student to search, "Well, it's down to you, Jimmy".

Without this implied process, the usual phrase is "it's up to me/you".

Comment: A quick ngram check suggests that you are more or less right. It looks like "down to" is used equivalently to "up to", but significantly less often. But that this is a change that happened in the second half of the 20th century.